# Meaning of jazz title "Shaw-nuff"

Tags: meaning

There is a famous jazz song called "Shaw-nuff". Does this title have a real meaning, or is it pure "scat"?

Comment: It's not onomatopoeia. It's phonetic spelling of a slurred or slang pronunciation of the words. Onomatopoeia is when a word approximates the sound of the thing it represents, like "buzz" for the sound of bees.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On first glance I understood it as a play on words of "[sure enough](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sure+enough)". I was right, though I didn't know the reason for calling a song in this way. I soon found [the answer](http://music.ippreciation.com/?q=node/380):

> Among the tracks recorded in the spring of 1945 was “Shaw Nuff,” its name inspired by the manager and booking agent Billy Shaw who had helped find work for Parker and Gillespie when few others recognized their importance.

For those who are interested, a little information on various uses of the more common *sho' nuff* can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sho%27nuff).

Comment: That may be why the first word is spelled _Shaw_, but it might be worth mentioning that other variants (such as _sho-nuff_ and _sho 'nuff_, e.g.) had been used to spell _sure enough_ colloquially for quite some time.

Comment: @J.R. Fo' sho;.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like it's just the slurred form of "sure enough". That kind of slurring is fairly characteristic of some accents, especially in the South.

Answer (score 1):

The title of that jazz song is a play on words of the phrase "sure enough". I couldn't find any other explicit meanings online, and this seems to be the only viable one.